# Order of multiplication in chain rule?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, vector-analysis

I am trying to figure out the order of multiplying things when taking the chain rule.

For example, if I have a function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

I take the gradient of a composite with $g:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, where $h(y)=f(g(y))=f(x_o+Py)$ and so $g=x_o+Py$, then is $\nabla h=P\nabla f$ or is it $\nabla h = \nabla f P$?  (obviously $\nabla g=P$).

In wikipedia you can see it is inconsistent:
[image: chain rule from wikipedia]
It shows in the first example that $\nabla f(a)$ is first, and then in the second example, it shows that $\nabla f(a)$ is second.  What is the correct order?

Comment: Is it because the Jacobian matrix is transposed?

Comment: but you could easily transpose the other one and just switch the order, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following, I am assuming that $\nabla f$ is used to denote the gradient of a functional (function taking values in $\mathbb{R}$). (This is also a lot
more long winded than originally intended!)

In $\mathbb{R}^n$ the difference between the derivative and the gradient for a functional are often blurred, which
leads to confusion.

The distinction is blurred because, to some extent, the differences can be viewed as different conventions (a row vector vs. a column vector). The distinction becomes more important in non Hilbert spaces.

In terms of derivatives, we have $D h(y) = D f(g(y)) D g(y) = Df(x_0+Py) P$. (Note that $Dg(y) = P$ since $g$ is linear).

Note that for any linear functional $\phi: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$, there is a unique element $w \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that
$\phi(x) = w^T x$.

The derivative $Df(x)$ is a linear functional, so there is a unique element so it can be written as above, we use the notation $\nabla f(x)$ (the gradient) to denote this unique element.

That is, $Df(x)h = \nabla f(x)^T h$.

Now we want to compute $\nabla h(y)$.

Note that $D h(y) \eta = Df(x_0+Py) P \eta = \nabla f(x_0+Py)^T P\eta$, so we can write
$Dh(y)\eta = (P^T \nabla f(x_0+Py))^T \eta$ (note the transpose on $P$) so we
have
$\nabla h(y) = P^T \nabla f(x_0+Py)$.

Personally, I use the gradient representation when dealing with things from a geometric perspective, but generally use the derivative when computing.

Comment: okay, so $\nabla f$ can only be used when a _linear_ representation of the derivative is available.  And when a linear representation of the derivative is available, it doesn't matter whether we have $Df(x)h=\nabla f(x)^T h $ or $ Df(x)h=h^T \nabla f(x) $?

Comment: @Candic3: I',m not exactly sure what you are asking. In a Hilbert space you can **always** write a (continuous) linear functional in the inner product form. The derivative is always a linear operator, but only when the range is a scalar can we write it as above. Since we are in real space, we have $a^T b = b^T a$, so yes to the last question (although I'm not sure what you are asking about that.)

Comment: Sorry @copper.hat for being unclear.  My first comment is totally wrong.
 I guess what I am wondering is when to use $\nabla f$ to represent the derivative operator.  It seems like you are saying only when the range is a scalar can we write it like $\nabla f$ ?sometimes we do not have $\nabla f$ in a certain direction, (e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2726663/is-the-directional-derivative-fxd-always-equal-to-nabla-ft-d-or-only) so I am not able to express it as $\nabla f$.  This confuses me because I thought all linear operations could be represented by matrix/vector operations?

Comment: @Candic3: You have raised many things in the last comment. The 'standard' use of $\nabla f$ is in the context of an inner product which is real valued. If a function does not have a (Fréchet) derivative but has a directional derivative then it cannot necessarily be written using the gradient format.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that $g$ is given by
$$g:\quad {\mathbb R}^n\to{\mathbb R}^n,\qquad y\mapsto g(y)=a+P.y$$
for a certain $a\in{\mathbb R}^n$  and a linear $P$. Then $h$ is defined by
$$h(y):=f\bigl(g(y)\bigr)\ .$$
The chain rule  says that
$$dh(y)=df\bigl(g(y)\bigr)\circ dg(y)\ .\tag{1}$$
Now $$dg(y)=P\quad\forall\>y,\qquad{\rm and}\qquad  df(x).X=\langle \nabla f(x),X\rangle\quad\forall X\ .$$ Plugging this into $(1)$ we obtain
$$\langle\nabla h(y),Y\rangle=dh(y).Y=df\bigl(g(y)\bigr).\bigl(dg(y).Y\bigr)=\langle\nabla f\bigl(g(y)\bigr),PY\rangle=\langle P^\top\nabla f\bigr(g(y)\bigr),Y\rangle\ .$$
Since this is true for all $Y\in T_y$ we conclude that
$$\nabla h(y)=P^\top\nabla f\bigl(g(y)\bigr)\ .$$