# Is the directional derivative $f'(x;d)$ ALWAYS equal to $\nabla f^T d$? or only under certain conditions?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, convex-optimization, vector-analysis, gradient-descent

My professor always writes the directional derivative with the condition that the functionis $C^1$ smooth.
i see him write many times the directional derivative written as $f'(x;d)=\nabla f^T d$, but right next to it he writes "because $\beta - C^1 smooth$", where $\beta$ is the Lipschitz constant, and $C^1$ means that it is continuously differentiable up to and including the first derivative.

Is the directional derivative $f'(x;d)$ ALWAYS equal to $\nabla f^T d$?  or only under certain conditions?

EDIT
And does "differentiable" mean with regards to a certain direction?  Or if a function is differentiable, then does that mean it must be differentiable in all directions?  If the former, then does $C^1$ mean it is differentiable in ALL directions?

Answer (score 2):

That equality holds when $f$ is *differentiable* at $x$ (in the sense of having an appropriately good linear approximation at $x$). The standard theorem that one always proves is that $C^1$ implies differentiability. [And, of course, $(\nabla f(x))^\top$ will be the linear map that gives the good approximation.]

Comment: So then which is a stronger form of the directional derivative?  the one with the gradient dotted with $d$?  or the one with the directional derivative $f'$?  I often see the former used instead of the latter

Comment: The directional derivative may well exist (and be computed from the definition) even when $f$ *fails* to be differentiable. (You might find some of the discussion in [my lectures](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL5I-Eyk8l9FHdJUd9UujGcvumjCFPHbrd) 22 and 23 helpful.)

Comment: An example is $f(x,y) = x^2 + |y|$. It is not differentiable for $y=0$, but the directional derivative along the $x$ axis exists.

Comment: @LinAlg: More interesting is a function where *all* directional derivatives exist, but the function isn't even continuous!

Comment: Right, so then a few clarifications:  1) you're telling me that it is possible that the derivative can exist in ALL directions i.e. ($\forall d$), and yet there might not exist a linear operator to express it (i.e. $\nabla f^T*d$ is invalid/does not exist)?  2)  C^1 smoothness implies differentiability in all d
irections? If so, then can we say if a function is C^1 smooth, then that means
 that the linear operator $\nabla f$ DOES EXIST, and we can say $f'(x;d)=\nabla f^T d$ ?

Comment: Right. Differentiable implies continuous, and I'm telling you there's even a function with *all* directional derivatives at $0$ equal to $0$ that isn't continuous at $0$!! Be careful. You can *define* $\nabla f$ if just the partial derivatives exist; but it needn't have the appropriate "good approximation" properties. $C^1$ guarantees that it will. "Differentiable" means that latter property, not that there are directional derivatives in all directions. (Of course, it will imply that condition.)

Comment: - So, "f is C-1 smooth at x" means it has the "good approximation" properties at x and also means the partial derivatives exist at x, and also means it can be written as $\nabla f^T d$? 
        - And "f is differentiable at x" implies continuity, and means the partial derivatives of f at x exist, and also means it can be written as $\nabla f^T d$, but it might not have the "good approximation properties"?