# How to prove identity $\nabla f(x) = \nabla F(x)*F(x)$ for 2-norm squared when chain rule says otherwise?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, vector-spaces, vector-analysis, gradient-descent

I know that the chain rule says that $f(x)=h(g(x))$ and if we want the gradient then $\nabla f = \nabla h*g'(x)$.

I am trying to prove the identity:

$\nabla f(x) = \nabla F(x)*F(x)$  when $f(x)=\frac{1}{2}||F(x)||^2$ and $F:\mathbb{E_1}\rightarrow\mathbb{E_2}$ where $\mathbb{E}$ is a Euclidean space and $F$ is a $C^1$ smooth mapping.

I am struggling with this because it seems to me like based on the definition for chain rule that I said above then wecan say $f(x)=h(g(x))$, and $h(y)=1/2||y||^2$ and $g(x)=F(x)$.  Then obviously $\nabla h=F(x)$, but then how do I get $\nabla F$ for the next part?

**question:**
Unless we are able to assume that $\nabla F=g'(x)$, and hence also assume that $g'(x)=F'(x)$ then how can I get this identity to work out?

and then in general when can I assume that the derivative equals the gradient?  I was told to not assume that in general.  thanks.

Comment: $||F(x)||^2=\langle F(x),F(x)\rangle$. Product rule rules...

Comment: thanks.  but it does not answer my question at the bottom

Comment: but @DavidC.Ullrich does the product rule apply to the inner product between operators on euclidean spaces the same way it applies to operators on vectors and real numbers?  Like, am I able to say $\frac{1}{2}<F(x),F(x)>=F(x)^2$ ?

Answer (score 3):

When in doubt, use coordinates.

If $F\colon\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$, we can write $F(x) = (F_1(x),\ldots, F_m(x))$, where $F_i\colon \mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$. Also, $\|F(x)\|^2 = \sum_i F_i(x)^2$. Then we have

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j}(x) = \frac\partial{\partial x_j}(\frac 12 \sum_i F_i(x)^2) = \sum_i F_i(x)\frac{\partial F_i}{\partial x_j}(x) = 
[\,F_1(x)\,\ F_2(x)\ \ldots \ F_m(x)\,]
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial F_1}{\partial x_j}(x)\\
\frac{\partial F_2}{\partial x_j}(x)\\
\vdots\\
\frac{\partial F_m}{\partial x_j}(x)
\end{bmatrix}
$$

therefore,

$$\nabla f(x) = [\,F_1(x)\,\ F_2(x)\ \ldots \ F_m(x)\,]
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial F_1}{\partial x_1}(x) & \frac{\partial F_1}{\partial x_2}(x) &\ldots & \frac{\partial F_1}{\partial x_n}(x)\\
\frac{\partial F_2}{\partial x_1}(x) & \frac{\partial F_2}{\partial x_2}(x) &\ldots & \frac{\partial F_2}{\partial x_n}(x)\\
\vdots & \vdots & & \vdots\\
\frac{\partial F_m}{\partial x_1}(x) & \frac{\partial F_m}{\partial x_2}(x) &\ldots & \frac{\partial F_m}{\partial x_n}(x)
\end{bmatrix}.$$

Here we identify vector in $\mathbb R^m$ with $1\times m$ matrix.

What might be confusing is that we are often identifying vectors with matrices (either $n\times 1$ or $1\times n$) and so the RHS of the chain rule might be matrix multiplication, inner product or action of linear operator on vector depending on particular identifications. I know it confused me a lot. But!

When in doubt, use coordinates.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Ennar, but I am still confused.

1) Which part of the premise of the question allows us to use $\nabla F$ to represent $F’(x)$?  Is it the part about it being $C^1$ smooth? or the part about mapping between Euclidean spaces?  I would have thought that since we don’t know what $F(x)$ we cannot immediately say that $F’(x) = \nabla F$.
2) What do you mean when you say “use coordinates”?  What are you using when you don’t use coordinates?

Comment: 3)  At the end of your answer, you seem to be implying that I just need to sort of finagle with $F(x)$ and $\nabla F(x)$ in terms of their order of multiplication until things work out? Otherwise I am not seeing a way to determine the order in which to multiply these.  thanks

Comment: @jaja, 1) This is a matter of notation. Personally, I would only use $\nabla F$ for functions of type $\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R$ and $F'$ for functions of type $\mathbb R\to \mathbb R^n$. It is not clear to me what are the dimensions of your Euclidean spaces, so I used general $\mathbb R^n \to\mathbb R^m$. Notice that I avoid using notation as I can't guess how you are using it from your post. I just use Jacobian of $F$, which is matrix representation of (total) differential of $F$. You can think of $\nabla F$ and $F'$ to represent (total) differential as well.

Comment: 2) Leibniz rule and chain rule for multivariable functions, as well as known derivatives of familiar functions.

Comment: 3) I do not imply that. I wrote very explicit answer in terms of matrix multiplication. I just wanted to point out that we often identify vectors with appropriate matrices, and I did it as well when I wrote $[\,F_1(x)\,\ F_2(x)\ \ldots \ F_m(x)\,]$ instead of $(F_1(x),\ldots, F_m(x))$. The result will again be a matrix instead of a vector, but the identification is obvious. If you want to avoid these, you can write $\nabla f(x) = (DF(x))^t(F(x))$ where $DF(x)$ is differential of $F$ at $x$, $t$ denotes transpose, and $F(x)$ is a vector.

Comment: When I see $\nabla f(x)$ I usually assume "gradient".  So when I asked "what part about this question allows us to use $\nabla F$ to represent $F'(x)$" I am referring to whether the gradient exists. 
 Based on this question, the $C^1 smooth$ is a sufficient condition for that to happen: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2726663/is-the-directional-derivative-fxd-always-equal-to-nabla-ft-d-or-only

Comment: @jaja, well yes, if function is differentiable, then all of its partial derivatives exist and so does the gradient.

Comment: sufficient, but not necessary, it seems.